# Scrapy Bench / Benchmark command errors

Tags: scrapy, screen-scraping, benchmarking

I've installed Scrapy 0.22.2 and was able to run the DirBot code sample without any issues.  However, when I run the Bench command, I get some errors and exceptions.  Are there any issues below other than port 8998 not accepting connections?

```
    C:\>scrapy bench
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\tests\mocks
erver.py", line 198, in <module>
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'keys/cert.pem'),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\ssl.py", line 70, in __in
it__
    self.cacheContext()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\ssl.py", line 79, in cach
eContext
    ctx.use_certificate_file(self.certificateFileName)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'No such process'), ('BIO routin
es', 'FILE_CTRL', 'system lib'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file'
, 'system lib')]
2014-04-07 14:30:39-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-04-07 14:30:39-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11

2014-04-07 14:30:39-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEO
UT': 10, 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 1}
2014-04-07 14:30:40-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCons
ole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-04-07 14:30:42-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuth
Middleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, Def
aultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, Redirec
tMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-04-07 14:30:42-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMid
dleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddlew
are
2014-04-07 14:30:42-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2014-04-07 14:30:42-0500 [follow] INFO: Spider opened
2014-04-07 14:30:42-0500 [follow] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scrape
d 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-04-07 14:30:43-0500 [follow] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scrape
d 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-04-07 14:30:44-0500 [follow] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scrape
d 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-04-07 14:30:45-0500 [follow] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scrape
d 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-04-07 14:30:45-0500 [follow] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://localhost
:8998/follow?total=100000&order=rand&maxlatency=0.0&show=20>: Connection was ref
used by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machin
e actively refused it..
2014-04-07 14:30:45-0500 [follow] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-04-07 14:30:45-0500 [follow] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/exception_count': 3,
         'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefus
edError': 3,
         'downloader/request_bytes': 783,
         'downloader/request_count': 3,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 7, 19, 30, 45, 575000),
         'log_count/ERROR': 1,
         'log_count/INFO': 10,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 7, 19, 30, 42, 439000)}
2014-04-07 14:30:45-0500 [follow] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: getting the same error.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: I had the same error. My project uses version 0.24. I created a separate virtualenv and installes the latest version (1.0.5) and it works fine there. Not sure how relevant the results are if executed on a different version, but at least it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install `cffi` python package but before that you'll need to install `ffi`, that is `libffi-dev` and `libffi` on Ubuntu:

`sudo aptitude install libffi-dev libffi`

`sudo pip install cffi`

Also you'll need to install `libssl-dev` because it's used on `cryptography` python package.

After that you should reinstall scrapy using: `sudo pip install scrapy --upgrade`

If it doesn't solve the problem, install the last version of scrapy from github, tarball:

`https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/tarball/master`

It worked for me..

Comment: user3508310 seems to be on Windows. Would be interesting on how to accomplish this there.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who faces an issue like this nowadays should make sure to follow the [official installation instructions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html).

If an issue like this occurs after following the official installation instructions, you should [report it as a bug](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/contributing.html#reporting-bugs).